# Custom Build Messages for Long Running Custom Activity appears at once

Tags: custom-activity

I am using context.TrackBuildMessage() for writing custom Build log in my Custom Activity

The problem is my custom activity runs long for more than 3 hrs and log messages are displayed only when custom activity is completed. All the logs appeared at once

Is there a way to display custom messages in a Build log as and when they are logged so that I have a better understanding of where the build currently is during the execution period.

Answer (score 0):

The CodeActivity is single thread so every operation in a single workflow instance is executed on the same thread, including tracking.

You should check the workaround from [TFS2010 - Logging inside custom build activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204616/tfs2010-logging-inside-custom-build-activity) with a parallel statement.