# TFS Build 2013 - Variable scope and custom activities

Tags: tfs, build

I was trying to do something similar to the stackoverflow article referenced below and am finding I can't set values in the code activity. I seem to be able to read values OK. I suspect this has something to do with the scope of these. In the stackoverflow article the code implied that the variable was set for the loop,

> > I am after guidance on how to set these correctly or a way for my codeactivity to flag to exit the external DoWhile loop ?

Refs 
[StackOverflow Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204616/tfs2010-logging-inside-custom-build-activity)

[Code Activity article](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/29/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-4-Create-your-own-activity.aspx)

[image: My TFS Build Protoype]

Answer (score 1):

OK here is the missing story and is not in the MS doco that I have found.. 
 e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551(v=vs.120).aspx

Although MS document In, InOut, Out args their scope is not shared... i.e.

**WRONG View of the world**

XAML argument like MyBoolInOut  Inout is the same argument that the C# code is using , e.g.

public InOutArgument MyBoolInOut { get; set; }

thus you only need to change values in C# code to change the values in the TFS XAML

**Correct view of this handling**
The custom code activity variables are visible in the XAML BUT are different from the XAML arguments. i.e.

as below, your C# codeactivity args have to be manually linked to the XAML args

So even though XAML has arguments and C# have arguments, these are separate.

This is an area MS could greatly improve their doco in.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Activities;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities;

namespace SampleActivityLibrary
{
        [BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.All)]

        // Sample Acitivty that will Flip a bool from True to False or from False to True
        public sealed class SampleFlipInOutBoolean : CodeActivity<Boolean>
        {
            public InOutArgument<Boolean> MyBoolInOut { get; set; }

            protected override Boolean Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
            {
                Boolean MyBool = context.GetValue(MyBoolInOut);
                context.TrackBuildWarning("SampleFlipInOutBoolean: In Value of Bool: " + MyBool.ToString(), BuildMessageImportance.High);

                MyBoolInOut.Set(context, !MyBool);
                MyBool = context.GetValue(MyBoolInOut);
                context.TrackBuildWarning("SampleFlipInOutBoolean: Out Value of Bool: " + MyBool.ToString(), BuildMessageImportance.High);

                return MyBool;

            }
        }
}
```

[image]